Can I recover my funds lost due to the deprecation of BPFLoader2 management instructions?
I was trying to deploy a Solana program and accidentally used Solana CLI 1.14.29 with the command solana deploy instead of solana program deploy. The deployment transactions failed with the following errors:
BPF loader management instructions are no longer supported
Program returned error: Unsupported program id
I discovered that this happened due to the deprecation of BPFLoader2 management instructions:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/34424
It created an account owned by BPFLoader2 and took about 3 SOL. As a result, I can't close the account. How can I get my SOL back? Is there any instruction that allows me to recover my funds?
It seems strange that the official Solana CLI (even the legacy version) behaves this way, potentially causing you to lose your funds, as it appears the developers did not account for such a situation.

Unfortunately, the old loader has no way to recover funds sent to an account -- you can only write bytes or finalize the program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/f1dae55a36469dba6b9f050b80d2a1b52d7004e8/sdk/program/src/loader_instruction.rs#L12
It's operationally difficult to create new releases going back to all old versions for breaking changes like this, and likely wouldn't be useful. If there were a new release for all versions with a deprecation notice, there's no guarantee that users would use it. If a project is on a very old version, then it's likely never updating anything.
